# Conditions for non-normability of (nontrivial proper and nondense) subspace of non-normable space.

Tags: normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Lets $X$ be a non-normable topological vector space and let $Y\subset X$ be a proper subspace. Clearly if $Y$ is dense in $X$ then $Y$ must be non-normable too. Can we have that conclusion with weaker hypothesis? I mean, the non-normability of the ambient space implies the non-normability of a subspace for some weaker hypothesis that density (about the subspace)?

Thaks in advance

Comment: Well, the trivial subspace $\{0\}$ is always normable. So I suppose you may want to amend the question to "non-trivial proper subspace." By the way, it is "subspace" and not "subespace" :)

Comment: @Math1000 I thought it was clear but, for the sake of preciseness, I change it now. And yes, indeed, subspace. Just my spanish messing around.